# How to insert simple form value in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

**resources/view/index.blade.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Laravel</title>
    </head>
    <body>
          <form method="post" action = "/create">
            <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="firstname" /><br/><br/>
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="phone" /><br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
          </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Controller**

```
class StudInsertController extends Controller {

    public function insertform()
    {
        return view('index');
    } 

    public function insert(Request $request)
    {
        $fname = $request->input('fname')
        $phone = $request->input('phone');

        $data = array('fname'=>$fname,"phone"=>$phone);

        DB::table('user')->insert($data);

        echo "Record inserted successfully.<br/>";
        echo '<a href = "/insert">Click Here</a> to go back.';
    }
}
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});
Route::get('insert','StudInsertController@insertform');
Route::post('create','StudInsertController@insert');
```

I am new in laravel. Now, I want to store the form value into the database table but now, its not happening I have no idea what is wrong with this code. So, Please help me out to solve this problem.

Thank You

Comment: what is error ?

Comment: can you add the error?

Comment: when I click on submit button it show me nothing @Vipul. I am trying with `http://localhost/blog/` url where blog contain laravel files.

Comment: If you are new to laravel, you need to refer the official documentation which will guide through how to handle CRUD operations. because those codes are more simpler than yours. And they have a standard, a design pattern, a naming convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `POST` routes in Laravel are protected by [CSRF](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf). You will have to add a token to your form to make sure the post request is accepted by the server.

```
<form method="post" action = "/create">
    @csrf <!-- This blade directive generates <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="xyz..." /> -->
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="firstname" /><br/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="phone" /><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: when I click on submit but it redirect me on `localhost/blog/create` where it throw an error i.e. `Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_PARSE)
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$phone' (T_VARIABLE)`

Comment: You forgot a `;` after `$fname = $request->input('fname')`

Comment: Now, it throw `MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message` @Jerodev

Answer (score 0):

Your missing CSRF Token add this

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Comment: please tell me what is the use of `{{ csrf_field }}`

Comment: @Rudra for csrf token you can visit this https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf

Answer (score 0):

Add    _token in your form tag like this

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Laravel</title>
</head>
<body>
      <form method="post" action = "/create">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="firstname" /><br/><br/>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="phone" /><br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
      </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add {{ csrf_field() }} and action would be action = "{{url('/create')}}"